# How to make rvalue method correctly call move constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

I have base class with copy and move constructors like this:

```
class Test {
 public:
    Test( int i ) {
        iptr = new int( i );
    }
    Test( const Test & other ) {
        printf("copy constructor\n");
        iptr = new int( *other.iptr );
    }
    Test( Test && other ) {
        printf("move constructor\n");
        iptr = other.iptr;
        other.iptr = NULL;
    }
    virtual ~Test() {
        delete iptr;
    }
    virtual Test * copy() {
        return new Test( *this );
    }
    virtual Test * move() && {
        return new Test( *this );
    }
 protected:
    int * iptr;
};
```

I added a copy and move methods to allow polymorphic copying and moving the object from a pointer, that can potentialy point to an instance of some subclass.

However when i write the following

```
Test t1( 5 );
Test * t2 = t1.copy();
Test * t3 = Test( 6 ).move();
```

first case correctly calls copy constructor, but second case incorrectly calls copy constructor too.

Why does the constructor overloading not work properly and how do i make it to call the move constructor?

Comment: Why don't you "flag" the copy method as const to its instance ?

Comment: @LaurentG: Oh, i forgot. But it still calls copy constructor in both cases.

Comment: `return new Test(std::move(*this));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way any rvalue reference parameter is an lvalue inside a function, the object for which an rvalue ref qualified member function is called is an lvalue within that member function.

```
void foo(Test&& x) 
{ 
    /* here x is an lvalue ! */ 
    Test y(std::move(x)); // need explicit cast to actually move
}
```

Thus you need:

```
virtual Test * move() && {
    return new Test( std::move(*this) );
}
```

(Don't forget `#include <utility>`.)

The reason why `*this` is an lvalue is because pointer indirection always produces an lvalue where `this` is always a `T*` (or `T cv *`) within a member function of a type `T`. While the member function cv qualification affects the `this` pointer, the ref qualification of the function does not. (There is no "pointer to rvalue" or "pointer to lvalue" but only "pointer to const" or "pointer to volatile" etc.)

---

- [Rvalue Reference is Treated as an Lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue)
- [Rvalue reference: Why aren't rvalues implicitly moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351669/rvalue-reference-why-arent-rvalues-implicitly-moved)
- [C++ move constructor not called for rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406675/c-move-constructor-not-called-for-rvalue-reference)
- [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this/8610728#8610728)

Comment: why an rvalue becomes lvalue again inside a function?

Comment: @Youda008: I linked serveral related questions.